# Android - Open URL in background

Tags: android, http, url, hyperlink

There is this website for example http://website.com You can like stuff there, with a link like this for example: http://website.com/3020/hype. You have to go to that link to get the article (3020) liked. You can only like stuff when loged in.

I have this:

```
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();  
            String getURL = "http://website.com/3020/hype/";
            HttpGet get = new HttpGet(getURL);
            HttpResponse responseGet = client.execute(get, cookieStuff);
```

Where cookieStuff is the cookie string I got from loggin in.

This works, but it takes ages. Is there another option?

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is a nother option.. Internet connections and Database Connection should made in a AyncTask or Handler.. This will improve the time taken for connection (the connections will make in Background)..

here is a example for an async task:

> ```
> private class YourTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
>     @Override
>     protected String doInBackground(String... s) {
>
>         //Here you have to make the loading / parsing tasks
>         //Don't call any UI actions here. For example a Toast.show() this will couse Exceptions
>         // UI stuff you have to make in onPostExecute method
>
>     }
>
>     @Override
>     protected void onPreExecute() {
>         // This method will called during doInBackground is in process
>         // Here you can for example show a ProgressDialog
>     }
>
>     @Override
>     protected void onPostExecute(Long result) {
>         // onPostExecute is called when doInBackground finished
>         // Here you can for example fill your Listview with the content loaded in doInBackground method
>
>     }
> ```
>
> }

To execute an AsyncTask:

> new YourTask().execute("");

Comment: Thanks this works very well! Except I have one more problem, maybe you can help me with it. When I click the 'Like' button for the first time it takes like 3 seconds, fast enough for me. But any time after that it doesn't work anymore..

Comment: Everytime a button gets clicked it opens this asynctask: http://pastebin.com/ZKzMpXxL The first one works within 3 seconds, all requests after that takes like 2-3 minutes..